# Should serial downvoter be punished/notify

Tags: discussion, moderation, serial-voting

When I woke up this morning I noticed in my feed that I was a victim of the well-known serial downvoting tragedy. I have a really good idea of who it is, but this is not the goal of this post. It was my first time, so I spent pretty much all my free time today to read on the subject. Don't worry I'm not asking what to do, nor asking for mods attention since there are tons of other threads telling us what to do in these situations. To my surprise though there was no real discussion on what to do to stop those kinds of behaviors. Here is an interesting part of a famous [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857) related serial voting:

> There is no automated punishment or notifications.
>
> Currently, the serial voting script only reverses the votes, and takes
>   no other action except putting an event in your reputation history.
>   There is no automated ban for users who engage in serial voting, and
>   the only form of notification they receive that their votes were
>   reversed is "+1 undownvote" events in their reputation history if they
>   had downvoted answers (if they only downvoted questions or had only
>   upvoted things, they will not be notified in any way).
>
> Continual abuse of the system which causes multiple reversals can lead
>   to a suspension, but the review process for such a suspension is
>   completely manual. No automated flags are ever generated for this
>   behavior, though moderators do have access to some statistics that can
>   help fight repeat offenders. If you find you are the victim of serial
>   voting multiple times within a short time span, feel free to flag one
>   of your own posts for moderator attention and explain the situation so
>   they can investigate further.

Now, I have learned about the voting fraud detection script, score recalculation and pretty much everything related to serial voting on Meta, but no automatic actions to users actually doing it was ever mentioned.

From all my research, the only place I saw people arguing on that subject was in comments on a question asking what to do when being serial voted. Like all of this was not relevant. Well,

**This is not trivial**

People are always arguing regarding the reputations and this is not where we should focus in my opinion. Quite frankly I don't care about the reputation I lost, even if the script doesn't catch my particular case, my reputation loss is the last thing on my mind. **The problem I have is with the downvotes.**

Especially because **serial downvoters will often focus on downvoting new answers with very few votes which often results on people not even reading or paying attention to that answer.** And this is where it is getting relevant.

I understand this is probably asking for resources that moderators don't have, but not punishing serial voters even the first time is probably generating more job and noise to moderators than just taking care of it right away.

I'm only trying to see other users' opinions, but I really think it is ironic that people serial downvoting not only are not getting any kind of punishment, but receive a +whatever rep because the votes are canceled...

**EDIT**

Obviously, this post was not accepted by the community and it is fine. But I just can't let it be as it is and not explain myself regarding what I was trying to underline.

I've read every feedback given by users and the majority of them are saying that banning someone for a first serial downvote is *overkill* well,

**I agree**

Also, people are saying that the script is already reverting the downvotes and is doing a good job since it catches more than that,

**I agree**

Finally, people say that serial voters are seemingly small in number compared to the community,

**I agree**

But even considering all that, above all, serial voting is not a wanted behavior and is clearly not that of a marginal behavior since almost every user commenting my post has experienced it. I don't think the above sayings are in any way a reason not to try to improve the system as it is right now. By the way, my critic is not in any way towards moderators. As I said, in my first version of the post, maybe they don't have the resources to manually do that, I was only trying to start a discussion that could bring some ideas to the table.

**Clarification on the word** ***punishment***

Maybe I used the wrong term here. What I meant and as I said in a comment, why would it be so bad to notify someone that the script catches as a serial voter?

I'm not in considering banning or suspending someone for the first offense. **Punishment could be a notification as I said, not giving him/her his/hers reputation back, or any other suggestions I was trying to discuss in this post.**

People also mentioned **false positives** a lot,

Maybe I'm completely wrong here, but in my opinion, this is an argument in favor of my way of seeing the problem. False positives have almost no chance to exist in that case. I can't imagine that someone will immediately be alarmed by the fact that five of his posts are downvoted. I'm talking about 20,30 or even more answers being downvoted in minutes. Can that be falsely positive? I don't think so.

Since the script catches almost every behavior of the kind, the entry point to such a new feature exists. We already know who is doing it and when, so why not sending a notification with an auto-generated message or maybe removing some of the serial voter's reputation which is clearly justified since he/she is not acting professionally.

Comment: ...but you're presuming that this behavior isn't logged somewhere.

Comment: In the very statement you quoted, it mentions that repeat offenders *can* be suspended, and that it's a manual process. That's good, because it means there won't be false positives, and the appropriate punishment, if one is appropriate, can be given.

Comment: @Makoto I'm not presuming anything. I'm just saying no automatic punishment is made that is all.

Comment: Well, no.  I wouldn't want a machine banning me based on a false positive.

Comment: @KevinB I agree with you, but can we sincerely think all cases are taking care of ?

Comment: We can't know for sure, that's privileged information.

Comment: @Makoto Well, you're the one presuming that I meant banning now... Maybe only a notification is enough, I don't know.

Comment: @KevinB  I did not ask the question literally, but more in order to emphasize the fact that waiting for repeated offenses is not always the right approach.

Comment: The only realistic punishment for aberrant voting is to strip them of the right to vote; effectively, reduce their rep to 1; effectively, *ban* them.  Warnings are given in certain cases but that's at the discretion of the moderator.  I'm not really sure what you're looking for anymore; an automated wag of the finger doesn't sound particularly valuable.

Comment: i mean... are you suggesting that users, regardless of whether or not they did it on purpose, on their first offence, should be made aware that they broke rules? if it's just a line in their reputation history, i could see that, but... much more than that, seems a bit much. If they do it repeatedly to the point they need to be contacted, they probably will be.

Comment: Aww, you broke your cherry.  Welcome to the club.

Comment: @KevinB are you suggesting you have ever seen someone reporting serial voting and find out it was not on purpose? Come on, if I get 5 or even 10 of my answers downvote I don't even ask myself why. But getting a ton of answers downvoted in a short period of time is either a one chance in a million or a wanted behavior from someone.

Comment: Right, and that occurrence will be reversed, and the user will see the reversal. What more do you want?

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, I'm kinda of new on Stack and found it really troubling how many people reported that kind of behavior and was really asking myself why can someone do that and not get even the slightest attention.

Comment: @scharette:  Again...you're assuming that this kind of thing isn't logged anywhere.  It may not be made prevalent as a *warning* to the perpetrator, but there's no way that it escapes the attention of moderators.

Comment: @KevinB The user serial voting won't see any reversal he will just get is reputation back and since every thread on the matter suggests to victims to not do anything, how many times is considered repeated offenses...

Comment: `how many people reported that kind of behavior` given the millions of users on Stack Overflow, it could be argued the number is actually spectacularly low.

Comment: @Makoto if this information is so privileged as you both suggest how do you know for sure then?

Comment: *"The user serial voting won't see any reversal"* i'm not positive that is true. Pretty sure My votes were at one point reversed, and i recall seeing them, but i'm not sure how to even begin looking for that in my profile at this point with 63 pages of reputation history.

Comment: **Because if the perpetrator does this again, they are very usually banned.**  We don't know when or how often that trips since we're not moderators, but **it happens.**

Comment: @Pekka웃 If this kind of behavior, compared to the entire community as you said was not _spectacularly low_, why be on this site anyway?

Comment: Perhaps the [Inverted pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_pyramid_(journalism)) would be better for this question (TLDR)?

Comment: It's happened to me overnight :(   12 downvotes, with some of those on highly scored (gold badge) answers.

Comment: This is a really obnoxious problem. Whatever method they are using to reverse serial voting is way too overzealous. I keep getting hit by random "serial voting reversed" from people upvoting me. The latest was apparently because I was awarded a +100 bounty. I don't know how that qualifies as "serial voting". Really moronic algorithm if it can't take the human element into consideration.

Answer (score 7):

> I understand this is probably asking for ressources that moderators don't have, but not punishing serial voters even on the first time is probably generating more job and noise to moderators than just taking care of it right away.

Nonsense. Not every instance of serial voting is malicious. It is possible to accidentally serially vote someone. Whether through pure accident (you frequent the same tag, and they happened to run across 3 of your answers) or through less accidental yet not malicious means (they found your profile and looked through your answers, but they weren't voting on all of them, just a few that caught their eye).

Repeated serial voting, especially against the same person, is far more likely to be malicious than accidental. And thus, that's when moderators are called in.

There's that saying about better a hundred guilty go free than one innocent person sent to prison.

So I fail to see how treating all serial voting as abuse of the highest order would reduce "noise to moderators".

> I'm only trying to see other users opinions, but I really think it is ironic that people serial downvoting not only are not getting any kind of punishment but receive a +wathever rep because the votes are cancelled...

That is not true. They don't get *automatically* punished. If they keep it up, they *will* be dealt with.

We don't use scripts to punish users. We only punish users through *human* review of their actions.

> Especially because serial downvoters will often focus on downvoting new answers with very few votes which often results on people not even reading or paying attention to that answer.

For a few hours, yes. Then the votes get reversed and it's all over with.

Furthermore, I don't find your statement to be accurate. Serial downvoters do target low scoring answers/questions. But they aren't aiming for new ones; they don't care whether they're new or old. This has certainly been my experience with serial downvoters. They (presumably) go to your profile, sort by votes, go to the last page, and start downvoting.

Any prolific user will have some number of low-scoring older answers, especially if they're on a tag that doesn't get much traffic.

Comment: _So I fail to see how treating all serial voting as abuse of the highest order would reduce "noise to moderators"._ Did I say that ?

Comment: @scharette: You asked to punish someone for a first offense, even though we don't even know if it was a genuine offense or not.

Comment: _through pure accident (you frequent the same tag, and they happened to run across 3 of your answers)_ this is nonsense... I'm talking about serials voters why are you even saying this... I'm talking about downvoting 20,30 or even more answers in a matter of minutes...

Comment: @scharette: The serial voting script catches more than just that. It catches irregularities like upvoting the same person's posts repeatedly, even if you only upvote once or twice a day. Or downvoting someone's posts in the same way. And so forth. Those are *all* examples of serial voting.

Comment: I said punish or notify... You all exagerate what I'm saying which result in completely destroying what I'm trying to underline.

Comment: I never said to ban the user or anything close to that. Just a notification message original anything that could maybe at least make the serial voter think about what he did.

Comment: @scharette: You said "not punishing serial voters even on the first time", and "not getting any kind of punishment". Your focus on punishment couldn't be more clear. As for notification, they are already notified when their votes are reversed, if they are downvotes that cost them rep.

Comment: Would it be so bad to notify someone that a strange behavior has been caught by a script ? Thats all I'm saying...

Comment: @scharette: "*I never said to ban the user or anything close to that.*" What other "punishment" is there? That's pretty much what we have as far as punishment goes: temporary bans and permanent bans.

Comment: Again, destroying a post for one word that you interpret like you want. Anyway this is already a dead post for me, I will move on and not waste more time explaining what I meant. Sincerely, I really appreciate the time you spent giving me your opinion even though we don't agree. Thank you.

Comment: @scharette: "*Again, destroying a post for one word that you interpret like you want.*" I'm sorry; my mind reading device is currently broken, so at present I am only able to understand your meaning by what you say, not what you *believe* that you said or what you meant. It would perhaps be good if, in the future, you made more of an effort to be clear, for the benefit of those whose telepathic tools are on the fritz.

Comment: You're right my bad .

Comment: I've had plenty of serial downvoters target my most popular posts, rather than my lowest-scoring ones. Just another datapoint.

Comment: Well maybe I was wrong on that point, obviously I had to based my opinion on what happened to me. I don't have any popular post, but every downvoting was made on answer with 0 votes that were not accepted. Anyway, all that asides popular are not, this kind of behavior should in my opinion get more attention. Now the "punishment" can be debatable, it can act on any form, notifications, not getting his reputation back, etc. I was trying to ask the community for alternatives regarding this issue but clearly using "punishment" was not the right approach.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Also, I follow your threads/answers a lot since you really deliver quality. Every people destroying me for posting the opinion are people with high reputation. Obviously, someone with the kind of rep like you even if someone makes it his day job to go downvote all your answers it won't even be close to being apparent. But for new users deciding to use their free time ans join the community, I'm pretty sure getting all their answers downvoted can discourage them even if it is for one day.

Comment: I also edited my post regarding the "punishment" term.